# How to multiply element row-column with element column-row in a matrix, for all elements?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a very large matrix and would like to multiply element [a,b] with element [b,a] and then repeat for each other element.

Say I have a matrix a:

```
a <- matrix(c(1:9), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
```

that gives a matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

- So, for example, for element `a[1,1]` I would multiply `a[1,1]` with `a[1,1]` giving 1
- Next element `a[1,2]` I would multiply `a[1,2]` with `a[2,1]` giving 8

Repeating this for every element should give:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    8   21
[2,]    8   25   48
[3,]   21   48   81
```

which I calculated using:

```
b <- matrix(c(a[1,1] * a[1,1], a[1,2] * a[2,1], a[1,3] * a[3,1],
              a[2,1] * a[1,2], a[2,2] * a[2,2], a[2,3] * a[3,2],
              a[3,1] * a[1,3], a[3,2] * a[2,3], a[3,3] * a[3,3]) , 
            byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
```

My code is extremely choppy and would be impossible to use for very large matrices. Is there any code that can do this using loops or any other easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could multiply `a` with its transpose

```
a * t(a)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    8   21
#[2,]    8   25   48
#[3,]   21   48   81
```